# FrameBuffer texture reading black for each pixel WebGL

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, post-processing

So I just got into WebGL graphics a few months ago and I wrote a class to add a filter to any render. The only problem with it was, the framebuffer texture always returns black. I don't know why and it seems like there isn't more than a handful of examples using multiple shaders so it would help a lot if y'all know anything about this.

Here's my code:

```
export { FXFilter }
import { Shader } from "./shader.js";

class FXFilter {
    constructor(gl,vss,fss) {
        // Create a texture to render the triangle to
        this.texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
        
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 400, 400, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

        // Create a framebuffer and attach the texture
        this.framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffer);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture, 0);
        
        this.quadbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quadbuffer);
        var x1 = -1;
        var x2 = 1;
        var y1 = -1;
        var y2 = 1;
        gl.bufferData(
            gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
            new Float32Array([
                x1, y1,
                x2, y1,
                x1, y2,
                x1, y2,
                x2, y1,
                x2, y2,
            ]),
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        
        this.shader = new Shader(vss,fss);
        this.shader.setup(gl);
        
        this.resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.shader.program, "resolution");
        
        this.positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.shader.program, "position");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionAttributeLocation);
    }
    
    render(gl) {
        gl.useProgram(this.shader.program);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        gl.uniform2f(this.resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quadbuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }
}
```

I tried to rearrange the order that I bound the buffers but that gave the same result.

Here's my vertex shader:

```
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
```

Here's my fragment shader:

```
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    void main() {
      // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
      vec2 zeroToOne = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
  
      // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
      vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    
      // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
      vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
      
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, clipSpace);
    }
```

Comment: What does your shaders look like? (`vss` and `fss`)

Comment: The code you show creates a texture and a framebuffer, attaches that texture to the framebuffer, then in the render method you set the default framebuffer(screen) and render the contents of the texture to the screen. At no point you actually fill the texture with anything.